# A complex causative form

Tags: causative-have, causative-get

I would like to learn how can I rewrite the following sentence in the causative form.

" Mary asked Jamie to get her car to repaired"

Can we say

" **Mary had Jamie have/had her car repaired** "

Thanks :)

Comment: *Mary asked Jamie get her car to repaired."* This is not correct English. It should read *"Mary asked Jamie to get her car repaired"*.

Comment: @ Murat: Native speakers simply wouldn't string two syntactically distinct instances of ***to have*** together like that. It's "jarring". Colloquially we'd almost certainly use ***to get*** in at least one position simply because that's much more common/casual. And if you were *going* to use the same verb twice, it doesn't sound so bad if you're already in the most casual "register", so *"Mary **got** Jamie **to get** her car repaired"* is a credible, if ungainly, utterance.

Comment: ...your second question seems to be the same ugly repetition plus an irrelevant extra ***has*** just to rub salt in the wound.

Comment: well thanks for answers @FumbleFingers can I ask that when we say " Mary got Jamie to get her car repaired" does the sentence have past tense ? for me it sounds Mary asked ( the past tense form ) but it is not clear whether the car was repaired or not and can we apply  this form to my second sentence  " Hannah got Ruairi to get Adam fired"

Comment: It's unambiguous with *had* or *got* that the action succeeded (that's to say Mary successfully got Jamie to do whatever she wanted done). With *asked*, we've no idea whether Jamie already did what he was asked to do, refused to do it, or agreed to do it but simply hasn't complied with the request yet.

Comment: You're just playing with ungainly forms for nothing. People don't even *think* like that, let alone *talk* like that.

Comment: thank you for explaining the difference of usage  ask and get  in terms of meaning between. Well can I ask that   " Mary got Jamie to got her car repaired " makes a sense?

Comment: the question, which I see may be somewhat malleable, currently stands grammatically correct at, "Mary had Jamie have her car repaired " - though it's ungainly.

Comment: Is this some kind of academic exercise or homework problem? Most people don't wonder aloud how "rewrite the following sentence in the causative form." In any case, try, _Mary had Jamie get the car repaired_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is tricky. The first example you give is ungrammatical, and so the second example is as much a re-wording as it is a correction.

This feels an awful lot like proofreading, but:

> (a) Mary had/made Jamie have her car repaired

Sentence (a) is grammatical, if a little unusual.

> (b) Mary had Jamie get the car repaired

As suggested by [J.R.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/113/j-r), sentence (b) is more idiomatic.